# Assigning pointer in an if in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, null

I have no problem doing this:

```
if (SomeClass* objName = getThatClass())
```

if `objName` is not `NULL` then the condition will be true, however I want to do this:

```
if ((SomeClass* objName = getThatClass()) != NULL && someBoolIsTrue)
```

But then I am getting an error at * saying it expects a primary expression before that(* token). Show how can I assign a value and then check something else within the same if?

Note:
The reason why I want to this is because, I want `objName` to be only visible within the if scope, the other reason is I combine this if statement with other statements, so separating two conditions wouldn't work either.

Comment: Why are you declaring objName at all?

Comment: I guess he wants to use it in the body of the `if` but not outside of it.  I didn't even know that it was allowed to define variables at that point.

Comment: @antlersoft because I want to use `objName` within the scope of if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
if (SomeClass* objName = someBoolIsTrue ? getThatClass() : 0)
```

This isn't completely equivalent though.  Since `getThatClass()` is only called if `someBoolIsTrue`, if the `getThatClass()` call has side-effects, there will be a difference in behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by invalid syntax?

Comment: @SarpKaya The language has grammar rules that your program must conform to or it won't be accepted. Those rules prohibit putting a variable declaration inside an expressions like you were trying to do.

Comment: @bames53 If it is invalid then how come it compiles without any errors & warnings?

Comment: @bames53: What I meant was that your second statement (which was getting the error) wasn't valid syntax, but I guess that didn't need saying.  I've updated my answer

Comment: I see what you mean now. I thought you were saying that your answer was invalid syntax.

Comment: This avoids a call to `getThatClass()` when `someBoolIsTrue` is `false`.  If `getThatClass()` has any side effects, then the functionality is changed.  That may or may not be an issue, but would better be clearly mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @TonyD: True -- changed.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that your first example was valid C++, that you could define a new variable in that context.  But in any case that assignment is obviously not a "primary expression".  So you can change your second example to

```
SomeClass *objName;
if ((objName = getThatClass()) != NULL && someBoolIsTrue)  
    ....
```

(Actually I would probably use more parentheses too, but they are not syntactically necessary).

Comment: That's not what I want to do, my intention is to use `objName` within the same scope of if statement

Comment: Well you will have it in the scope of the if statement :)  You mean you want *not* in scope anywhere else.  You should accept @VaughnCato's answer, even I upvoted it.  But if the surrounding function is not huge, then is there any real benefit in restricting the scope?  And if it is huge then, *break it up*.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep the variable scoped via the if statement, then you could still do:

```
if ((SomeClass* objName = getThatClass()) != NULL)
{
    if(someBoolIsTrue)
    {
        // whatever happens when both are true
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this really work?  I would have guessed the `!=` operator will generate exactly the error that the OP is reporting.

Comment: This wouldn't work with if, else if ... sequence conditions. For instance let's say I have an else at the end of outermost if scope. If `someBoolIsTrue` is false, then it wouldn't simply go to the else block.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala
You don't need to use != NULL here anyway you can just use `if (SomeClass* objName = getThatClass())  {}` but the idea is just to do everything in one scope and this answer does not answer my question.

Comment: Clearly it would work if you remove the `!= NULL`, but I am wondering whether the  example as given works.

Answer (score 0):

Vaughn Cato's suggestion's great if you don't need any side effects that `getThatClass()` may have.

---

It's a bit heavyweight, but you can create your own "long"-circuit ternary operator...

```
template <typename T>
T iff(bool b, const T& on_true, const T& on_false)
{
    return b ? on_true : on_false;
}

if (SomeClass* objName = iff(someBoolIsTrue, getThatClass(), 0))
    ...
```

---

Definitely not recommended, but for interests sake you can also use bitwise operations:

```
if (SomeClass* objName = (SomeClass*)((uintptr_t)getThatClass() &
                                      (someBoolIsTrue ? (uintptr_t)-1 : 0)))
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is compiler dependent. Most compiler should compile your code. This is ok if you want your pointer visible within your if block.

Comment: That's not true... the language Standard allows a new variable to be defined only before any `(` token opens an expression instead....